# How to send PCM Raw Audio Data to server using socket and get back PCM Raw Audio Data and play audio file in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, sockets, voip, audio-streaming, rtp

I have an app requirement that Implementing a VOIP functionality in iPhone application.

I have little bit success for connect server using socket.

I facing a few problem in that.

I have implement below code for audio recording.

```
-(void)open {
    NSError *error;

    m_capture = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    AVCaptureDevice *audioDev = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    if (audioDev == nil)
    {
        printf("Couldn't create audio capture device");
        return ;
    }
    //m_capture.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;

    // create mic device
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioIn = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDev error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        printf("Couldn't create audio input");
        return ;
    }

    // add mic device in capture object
    if ([m_capture canAddInput:audioIn] == NO)
    {
        printf("Couldn't add audio input");
        return ;
    }

    [m_capture addInput:audioIn];
    // export audio data
    AVCaptureAudioDataOutput *audioOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
    [audioOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    if ([m_capture canAddOutput:audioOutput] == NO)
    {
        printf("Couldn't add audio output");
        return ;
    }

    [m_capture addOutput:audioOutput];
    [audioOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    [m_capture startRunning];
    return ;
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{


}
```

Above code have `captureOutput` function. This function is continuous capture audio.

I have no idea how to send PCM Raw Audio Data to server and get back PCM Raw Audio Data and play an audio in **iPhone**.

Server coding is done. Server get back me PCM Raw Audio Data.